# Calling a function with a Collection as an argument

Tags: java, collections

I need to call a function that takes a collection as an argument:

```
public static <T extends Type1> Type2 method(Collection<T> my_collection)
```

To define my collection, since Collections can't be instantiated, I defined an `ArrayList<T> a`. I am now trying to call this function with a as an argument, but eclipse says my function is not defined for the type Collection. Yet, my type T extends Type1 as in the method definition. Did I not call it correctly?

EDIT

I basically just created an array with elements of type T: `ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<T>();` that I populated and called method. The exact error in method is: `The method method(ArrayList<T>) is undefined for the type`

Comment: Please share the calling code as well.

Comment: Can you show the part of your code that calls this function and the exact error please?

Comment: I don't understand the method header. Type2 is the return value? So what is '<T extends Type1>'? And how do you parameterize a static method?

Comment: Please update the question and don't put it in the comment.

Comment: You need to learn more about generics.

Comment: @teaLeef Post the *complete* code. An MVCE. We're not going to bother with guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works without problems in my test:

```
public class Test
{


    static class Type2
    {
    }

    static class Type1
    {

    }

    static class TestT extends Type1
    {

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<TestT> l = new ArrayList<TestT>();
        Type2 type2 = method(l);
    }

    public static <T extends Type1> Type2 method(Collection<T> my_collection)
    {
        return new Type2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function will work for following :

```
ArrayList<Type1> a = new ArrayList<Type1>();
```

or Collection of any class extending `Type1`.

In `<T extends Type1> Type2 method(Collection<T> my_collection)`
`<T extends Type1>` the generic type `T` you will use should be extending `Type1` class.